# mysqli_fetch_array() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Getting error on my code can any one tell me what I am doing wrong and how to solve it or any one suggest me the more simple code after select query because I don't want to mess my code and it is not helping

Here is my Code

```
if(isset($_GET['ID'])){

$page_id = $_GET['ID'];

      $page_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $page_id);

$select_query = ("select ID, Title, image, Cost, Vid, content from mobs where ID=?"); 

$stmt = $con->stmt_init();
if(!$stmt->prepare($select_query))
{
    print "Failed to prepare statement\n";
}   
else
{
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $page_id);

    {
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); 
}

while($row->mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
    $post_id = $row['ID']; 
    $post_title = $row['Title'];
    $post_image = $row['image'];
    $post_cost = $row['Cost'];
        $post_vid = $row['Vid'];
            $post_cont= $row['content'];  
}
```

I am getting these errors

```
Notice: Undefined variable: row in 

Fatal error: Call to a member function mysqli_fetch_array() on a non-object
```

Comment: you're calling `$row->mysqli_fetch_array()` but not defining `$row` anywhere. Should it be `$result`?

Comment: check your field names........

Comment: I honestly don't know why you asked [`the same question earlier`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22523176/) and accepted [`it`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22523294/).

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's not the same question. There he was asking about `get_result`, and here he's asking about (the next function call, lol) `fetch_array`.

Comment: Because that problem was solved and new raised so that's why but again same problem raised 'Confused :('

Comment: Comparing both questions along with the answer given @JonathonReinhart it doesn't seem like the OP used Phil's answer, not completely anyway. Read the comments under the answer too.

Answer (score 3):

You're (incorrectly) combining the procedural and OOP-style calls.  See [`mysqli_result::fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array).

The correct object-oriented style call:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
```

Comment: @user3423422 You're welcome. Please remember to up-vote all answers that helped, and accept the one that ultimately solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the while statement to

```
**while($row=$result->fetch_array())**
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

$row is not an object. So you have got this error:

```
Call to a member function mysqli_fetch_array() on a non-object
```

in this line:

```
while($row->mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Should be :

```
while($row= $result->fetch_array())
```

Another thing:
in this  bind it seems that id is integer.

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $page_id);
```

if so then it should be:

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $page_id);
```